# opengl es 2.0 in snap to edge and snap to middle in Android programmatically

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-1.1, opengl-to-opengles

I tried to make snap to edge and snap to middle effect of line like Auto cad.

I used OPENGL ES 2.0 Android Technology to draw this line.

I successfully make effect for snap to edge. But, when I touch (Action Down - Touch Event)
the corner of line, it shows the snapping effect like small square in line corner.

But, After action up the touch on line corner, the snap effect will not able to clear.

**Note: This is my Problem.  when I touch the line starting point and Ending Point
the snapping effect came.but , after remove the touch on line , I don't know how to
clear the last shown snap effect.**

like how to clear the last shown snap effect vertex buffer memory?

Snap to edge Effect:
[image: Snap to edge Effect]